# Why pandas strftime raises a FutureWarning and how to avoid it?

Tags: python, pandas, string, date

I need to **parse a date column to a string**, it works, but I'm having some issues, first of all is not giving a string data-type as an output:

```
import pandas as pd  # No warning raised
exit_format = '%d-%m-%Y'
series = pd.Series([1,2,None] ,dtype='datetime64[ns]')
series.dt.strftime(exit_format)
```

This (intended behaviour) is not a big deal as can it can be fixed with `astype('string')` and replacing the `Nan`. But the worst thing is that if all values are NaN-Nat, I'm getting this `FutureWarning`:

```
# Warning raised!
series = pd.Series([None,None,None] ,dtype='datetime64[ns]')
series.dt.strftime(exit_format)

FutureWarning: In a future version, the Index constructor will not infer numeric dtypes when passed object-dtype sequences (matching Series behavior)
```

This seems to be come from a [known issue](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/45858) at pandas version >= 1.4.0 (mine is '1.4.1'). My question is, how can I make a nice workaround? Why this warning appears in the first place when all values are Nan? Preferably I'm looking for a solution that doesn't suppress the warning directly but his origin.

Basically I'm looking for a function that takes a date column to a string column but parsing NaNs as empty strings or treating the errors in a better way (like using a default value), but without giving a warning.

pd: a possible solution could be adding a non empty row at the end and deleting it, but I was wandering if there is some implemented function that is actually working well, without using tricks...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a bit more idiomatic way to take into account `NaT` values (Pandas>=1.0.0), as properly suggested by @finavatar:

```py
import pandas as pd

series = pd.Series([None, None, None], dtype="datetime64[ns]")

series = series.apply(lambda x: x.strftime("%d-%m-%Y") if x is not pd.NaT else x)

print(series)  # No warning message
# Output
0   NaT
1   NaT
2   NaT
dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

And with a non empty Series:

```
import pandas as pd

series = pd.Series(["04/03/2022", None, None], dtype="datetime64[ns]")

series = series.apply(lambda x: x.strftime("%d-%m-%Y") if x is not pd.NaT else x)

print(series)  # No warning message
0    03-04-2022
1           NaT
2           NaT
dtype: object  # == string
```

Comment: Yes, this looks indeed better, still a trick but I guess being a but nothing else can be done, also this answer allows you to place a default value in a easy way, which makes it more complete in my opinion.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem too recently.
What I did to bypass this warning is simply to check if the date value is non NaN first before using strftime.

Example:

```py
if df['date'].isnull().values == False:
  df['date'] = df['date'].dt.strftime('%b %d, %Y')
```

OR

if you need to check for ANY /ALL nan values for a date column:

syntax:

```py
df['your column name'].isnull().values.any()
df['your column name'].isnull().values.all()
```

Comment: I would say this is also a trick to avoid it, as appending a mock value and eliminating it, but It will definitely work so up-vote. I will wait a bit if there is any more complete answer though, if not, I will accept yours as the solution. And thanks for your answer! Welcome to SO.